# Why isn't my attempt to target_link_libraries to a dll file specified with an absolute ptah working?

Tags: c++, c, cmake

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OWqJF.png)

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.25)
project(HelloOpenGL)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 20)

INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/include)
LINK_DIRECTORIES(${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/lib)

add_executable(HelloOpenGL main.cpp src/glad.c)
TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(HelloOpenGL ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/lib/glfw3.dll)

file(GLOB SOURCE_FILES Code/*.cpp)
foreach(A_CPP_FILE ${SOURCE_FILES})
    get_filename_component(EXECUTABLE_NAME ${A_CPP_FILE} NAME_WE)
    add_executable(${EXECUTABLE_NAME} ${A_CPP_FILE})
    TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(${EXECUTABLE_NAME} ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/lib/glfw3.dll)
endforeach(A_CPP_FILE ${SOURCE_FILES})
```

make all cpp files in Code directory executable

Comment: You should link with an import library, not a dll.

Comment: can you not just `TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(HelloOpenGL glfw3)`? You already specified your link directory.

Comment: "not working" is not a problem description with which we can help you. What exactly is wrong with your setup? Do you got an error message? Please, (re-)read [ask] and edit your question post accordingly.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can just `TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(HelloOpenGL glfw3)`.

What you've done is wrong because if you want to specify a file to link to you're supposed to link to the `.lib` file for the `.dll` file.

See [the `target_link_library` docs](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/target_link_libraries.html), which list as one of the format options:

> **A plain library name**: The generated link line will ask the linker to search for the library (e.g. foo becomes -lfoo or foo.lib).